# Should a friendly URLs have ID at the beginning or at the end?

Tags: friendly-url

So I am planning to have friendly URLs for my site where each page has its own ID. So I found two common ways people do this:

```
http://www.example.com/page/123/slug-for-the-page
http://www.example.com/page/slug-for-the-page/123
```

Which one is preferred? What are arguments for and against each? I see that when typing the URL the second form is easier, because it is easier for browser to autocomplete from history or bookmarks. But for me it is really strange to have ID at the end.

I will use redirects to canonical URL for any slug which does not match the current one. But does people also do redirects from URL having slug, but no ID, when the slug is unique? For example, redirecting `http://www.example.com/page/slug-for-the-page` to `http://www.example.com/page/slug-for-the-page/123`.

Comment: Did anybody made any usability study about that? For example, does having ID at the beginning prevent users from being able to autocomplete their URLs? Does having ID at the end make it easier that IDs are incomplete because URL endings are truncated so URLs become invalid?

Answer (score 4):

First, some history:

The original reason for these URLs was that people wanted their database to be indexed by ID only. Indexing by slug (and enforcing uniqueness) was extra work for both the computer and the programmer. Rails made this style popular (`/page/1`).

But this style is fairly opaque to search engines. So people added the slug after the ID (`/page/1-slug-for-page`) to help the search engine (and the user). But the text as the end was irrelevant -- only the number mattered. The slug may not even be stored in the Database (sometimes it's auto-generated), and it wasn't indexed to save space.

> Which one is preferred?

For putting the ID in the URL, either style is OK, but the "number then slug" style is much more popular.

> I will use redirects to canonical URL for any slug which does not match the current one. But do people also do redirects from URL having slug, but no ID, when the slug is unique?

Just pick `ID` or `slug` and run with it.

1) If you lookup by ID, you should ignore the slug (they are only for search engines). You can easily redirect to the 'real' slug if you have the ID. (to correct any truncated URLs, etc.)

2) If you lookup by slug, your slugs need to be unique. (Most sites scope by date to make this easier). Once you're doing a database lookup on the slug, it's not clear why you would even need the ID in the URL. (They look ugly and are quite arbitrary, so it's better to drop them.) What you are proposing is extra work (for you and the computer) but I'm not sure it's useful.

Only high traffic sites need to worry about the index size/speed tradeoffs of indexing on slugs vs IDs. Even then, the difference can be minimized by doing tricks. (i.e. don't lookup the slug, look up the first 8 characters of the MD5 of the slug instead.)

Comment: The reason why you don't want only slug is that sometimes you have to rename a page and then you or have to change the slug or slug is in desync with the name of the page.

Comment: Anyway, I know that one is more popular, but I would like to know what are arguments for one of the other form of the ID in the URL. Are there any arguments? Is is really arbitrary, just a preference of taste? What are stories people have, experiences?

Comment: There is no consensus on the internet for the "best" URL scheme, so I'd say it's pretty arbitrary.

Answer (score 4):

One advantage of having the ID at the beginning:

In some contexts long URLs are cut off (e.g. by line breaks), so that only the first part of the URL is clickable. Now, if the ID is at the end (and therefore in the second part), clicking at the URL will lead to a 404. If the ID is at the beginning (and therefore in the first part), the link will usually still work.

Example? [Plain text mails from Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143295/urls-break-in-text-plain-version-of-emails):

> [image]

As you can see, the question URLs contain a line break, but the clickable part of the URL still contains the ID and so the links still work.